# File for loop C

Tags: c, for-loop

I'm trying to make a loop where my "soft" variable is taking the value of my other variable.
I'm trying to put each words of my file text (country-name, an espace, capital-of-country) in table.
But I can't find how to do it...

There's my program (partly) :

```
int main(){
    FILE *Africa;
    FILE *America;
    FILE *Asia;
    FILE *Europe;
    FILE *Oceania;
    int countryIndex = 0;
    int capitalIndex;
    char countryTable[15][30];
    char capitalTable[15][30];
    //FILE country[] = {Africa, America, Asia, Europe, Oceania};

    Africa = fopen("Africa.txt", "r");
    America = fopen("America.txt", "r");
    Asia = fopen("Asia.txt", "r");
    Europe = fopen("Europe.txt", "r");
    Oceania = fopen("Oceania.txt", "r");
    if (Africa == NULL || America == NULL || Asia == NULL || Europe == NULL || Oceania == NULL){
        printf("Error, failed when trying to open the continent file.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    for (FILE *country = {Africa, America, Asia, Europe, Oceania}){
        while (fscanf(country, "%s", countryTable[countryIndex]) != EOF){
            fscanf(country,"%s", capitalTable[countryIndex]);
            countryIndex++;
        }
        for (capitalIndex = 0; capitalIndex < countryIndex; capitalIndex++){
            printf("Country : %s - ", countryTable[capitalIndex]);
            printf("Capital : %s\n", capitalTable[capitalIndex]);
        }
    }

    /*while (fscanf(Africa, "%s", countryTable[countryIndex]) != EOF){
        fscanf(Africa,"%s", capitalTable[countryIndex]);
        countryIndex++;
    }
    for (capitalIndex = 0; capitalIndex < countryIndex; capitalIndex++){
        printf("Country : %s - ", countryTable[capitalIndex]);
        printf("Capital : %s\n", capitalTable[capitalIndex]);
    }*/

    fclose(Africa);
    fclose(America);
    fclose(Asia);
    fclose(Europe);
    fclose(Oceania);
    return 0;
}
```

If you need additional information do not hesitate.

Comment: Does `FILE *country = {Africa, America, Asia, Europe, Oceania}` compile for you?

Comment: `"%s"` risks buffer overflow and will not work to scan in country and capital names that include spaces.

Comment: You should check both the calls to `fscanf()`, and you should check that you get `1` back, rather than "don't get EOF".  When reading simple strings, the difference is mostly ignorable, but with more complex formats, and with numeric formats, etc, you can try to read one number and get 0 instead of EOF to indicate that what's in the input stream is not in fact a number.  If the country names are meant to be on one line and the capital city on the next, then you should probably use `fgets()` or POSIX `getline()` to read the line and then consider using `sscanf()` to parse the line as read.

Comment: Jean-Lou Gilbertas, "But I can't find how to do it..." --> what are you looking for? Code to do this assignment or some help with a specific problem?  I suggest you first start with trying to process only 1 file.

Comment: You made two attempts to create an array of FILE pointers. The first one (which is commented out) is only missing a `*`. It should be `FILE *country[] = ...` Just be sure that you open the files **before** creating the array, or it won't be initialized correctly.

Comment: I guess Jonathan answered my question. I'll try with the "&".

Comment: Well... As @chux - Reinstate Monica suggested, the code does not compile correctly...
He return me an error (expected ',' or ';' before )

Comment: Is... this a homework?

Comment: Please post an example of one of the input files.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, even if it's not the way I wanted to do it. By modifying my code like this :

```
int main(){
    char *continentName[] = {"Africa.txt", "America.txt", "Asia.txt", "Europe.txt", "Oceania.txt"};
    int nbrContinent = sizeof continentName / sizeof continentName[0];
    int countryIndex = 0;
    int capitalIndex;
    char countryTable[15][30];
    char capitalTable[15][30];

    for (int i = 0; i < nbrContinent; i++){
        FILE *continent = fopen(continentName[i], "r");
        if (continent == NULL){
            printf("Error, failed when trying to open the continent file.\n");
            return 1;
        }
        while (fscanf(continent, "%s", countryTable[countryIndex]) != EOF){
            fscanf(continent,"%s", capitalTable[countryIndex]);
            countryIndex++;
        }
        fclose(continent);

    }

    for (capitalIndex = 0; capitalIndex < countryIndex; capitalIndex++){
        printf("Country : %s - ", countryTable[capitalIndex]);
        printf("Capital : %s\n", capitalTable[capitalIndex]);

    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

This way it's easier and I get around the problem haha.
By doing so, each capital name is associated with its country in the tables. e.g. tabContinent[1] -> tabCountry[1]

I just put the retrieval of each word in my files in the initial for loop so that I don't have to redo one. To do this, I changed the type of my "FILE" variables into an array of chars that directly contains the names of the files in question. Then you have to be careful to close the files at the end of the loop but inside (otherwise the function doesn't end correctly and can cause problems when calling another function). And finally, add a for loop outside the first one (otherwise the values of the arrays are displayed each time the files are read) in order to enter the data retrieved in the arrays.

Comment: Update : The for loop doesn't work properly : it prints the same capitals and countries several times.

Comment: I don't get it @user3386109

Comment: Despite problems with `fscanf`, _etc_, this is automated much better. I don't think you need to store the previous countries, _viz_ `capitalTable` and `countryTable` if you print it as soon you receive it. You may wish to just automate the entire thing with [dirent.h](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/dirent.h.html).

Comment: Some good improvements.  Yet `while (fscanf(continent, "%s", countryTable[countryIndex]) != EOF){  fscanf(continent,"%s", capitalTable[countryIndex]);` is poor code as 1) its lacks a width limit allowing overrun 2) Does not parse names with a space 3) does not check return value of the 2nd read 4) does not check for a valid `countryIndex`.  Better to use `fgets()` twice and check `countryIndex`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica What do you mean by "its lacks a width limit allowing overrun", should I just set no limit on my table? In my text files, it is assumed that the names do not contain spaces (imposed by my teacher) but I agree with you... Is it so important to check the value of the second reading? Using the fgets function will force me to read each file letter by letter, won't that make the code heavier?

Comment: @Jean-LouGilbertas Code has a limit to the max storable string length as it uses `char countryTable[15][30]`.  That 30 limits string lengths to 29.  Code could use `"%29s"` to enforce that limit.

Comment: "Is it so important to check the value of the second reading?" --> When file input is as expected, then no.  Yet that is only excusable for a learner to trust that.  Robust code does not assume input is well behaved and takes steps to validate it.  Consider `while (countryIndex <  15 && fscanf(continent, "%29s", countryTable[countryIndex]) == 1 && fscanf(continent,"%29s", capitalTable[countryIndex]) == 1) { countryIndex++; }`.  Test the index and test reading against what  is wanted and not just against one of the unwanted return values like `EOF`.

Comment: " fgets function will force me to read each file letter by letter" --> Perhaps you are thinking of `fgetc()`?  `fgets()` reads a _line_ of input into a _string_.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica First of all, I don't understand the use of "%29s" which I have never seen before... Secondly, the code you show me works well, but I don't understand it: isn't it strange to do the operations in the condition of the while loop? Or maybe I misunderstood. The problem I see is that if I don't know the number of elements in my files, I can run my program but yours... (maybe there is a function to determine the max of an index of an array).
Finally, yes indeed, I made a mistake with the function, I was thinking of fgetc, sorry haha

Comment: @Jean-LouGilbertas Concerning the use of the _width_ 29 in `"%29s"`, research your favorite documentation concerning C library functions - or better, use `fgets()`. Re-organize code as desired if you do not want to put so many ops in a `while()`>  The key is that the functionality shown is needed.  "I don't know the number of elements in my file" --> then 15 may not be enough.  Since the number of countries in the world is less than [256](https://www.worldometers.info/geography/how-many-countries-are-there-in-the-world/), maybe use that?  Later on, you can research how to handle `N` countries.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica well it's not a bad Idea to set 256... Thank for the help! Should I post the final function here?

Comment: @Jean-LouGilbertas You can post you [own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).   **If** you truly have working code now and looking for a review, consider [Codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) and [how-to-ask](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @Jean-LouGilbertas Rather than 256, use `#define COUNTRY_COUNT 256` and use `char countryTable[COUNTRY_NAME_SIZE][COUNTRY_COUNT];`, ...